# formal subject & real subject in "It's obvious where our interest lies"

Tags: grammar

In this sentence "It's obvious where our interest lies", "it" acts as "formal subject" and "where our interest lies" is the real subject.

Am I right?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That is exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) *"**It** is obvious [where our interest lies]"*

Your example sentence is in the form of an **extraposition construction:**

- The grammatical **subject** is the dummy pronoun *"It"*.
- The expression *"where our interest lies"* is a subordinate content clause, which is called by some grammars (e.g. *CGEL*) as the "extraposed subject". An extraposed subject is NOT a kind of subject--it is merely an element in extraposed position.

Different grammars will often use different terms for "extraposed subject", and so, you will probably need to be aware of that (especially on tests). But be aware that that extraposed element is not a grammatical subject.

The basic version that corresponds to your example is:

- 2) *"[Where our interest lies] is obvious."*

Notice how the grammatical subject in version #2 is the content clause *"Where our interest lies"*.

There are grammatical diagnostic tests that can be used to help determine the subject of a clause. One such test is the **subject-auxiliary inversion** test, where the corresponding interrogative version is created. For your original version (*"It is obvious where our interest lies"*), the following is the corresponding interrogative version:

- 3) *"**Is it** obvious [where our interest lies]?"*

Notice how the subject and verb have switched positions (i.e. inverted). That shows that the pronoun "it" is the grammatical subject.

Again, be aware that different, er, "grammar" sources use different terminology, and their terminology will often be misleading (such as "formal subject" and "real subject", and sometimes even the term "subject" itself).

Comment: "An extraposed subject is NOT a kind of subject--it is merely an element in extraposed position." Can't we call it the notional/real subject?